Best way to go about vanity PDAs?
The most obvious idea to me is taking a seed as a parameter and grinding it off-chain to find whatever prefix/suffix you want, then submitting whatever seed + bump combination you found through the program.
But is there a better way?

that feels like it is likely the only way. pure grinding offchain
